# Icefaces push without using Ajax/Javascript

Tags: web-services, jsf, push, icefaces

I'm a total newbie with the jsf and ICEfaces frameworks, and we started to playing around with them a couple of weeks ago.

Now we are trying to perfom a push without using AJAX, in order to make this operation avaiable trough a WebService.

I found [this thread](http://www.icefaces.org/JForum/posts/list/18986.page), which seems to be something like we want to do, but I'm still a bit lost. The guy claims to have succeded:

> I wired my Renderable class into my
>   web service so it simply has to call
>   the appropriate method to request the
>   render.

Could anybody give me a hint on how to "wire" the WebService to the Renderable class?
I suspect there is something to do with the [PortableRendered](http://www.icefaces.org/docs/v2_latest/core/api/index.html), but as I told you, I'm still a bit lost.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example is the simplest case.  A sports score is updated in the web browser every two seconds using an ICEfaces push update.

The method ScoreManagerBean.postConstruct() is called after the managed bean is constructed for a new session.  This method starts a thread that calls PortableRenderer.render(sessionId) every two seconds, causing the new score to be pushed to the web browser.  In a real application, the push update would be run in some kind of callback function after receiving a message/trigger that data in the application has changed.

Exactly the same concept is used for more complex applications such as news-tickers and ebay-style auction sites.

Here is the managed bean class ScoreManagerBean.java:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.util.Random;

import org.icefaces.application.PortableRenderer;
import org.icefaces.application.PushRenderer;

@ManagedBean(name = "scoreManager")
@SessionScoped
public class ScoreManagerBean
{
    private int m_nPointsA = 0;
    private int m_nPointsB = 0;
    private PortableRenderer m_renderer;
    private String m_sessionId;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct()
    {
            FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            HttpSession session;
            session = (HttpSession)facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
            m_sessionId = session.getId();
            PushRenderer.addCurrentSession(m_sessionId);
            m_renderer = PushRenderer.getPortableRenderer(facesContext);
            new BidThread().start();
    }

    public String getCurrentScore()
    {
            return m_nPointsA + "-" + m_nPointsB;
    }

    private class BidThread extends Thread
    {
            public void run()
            {
                    Random r = new Random();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                    {
                            try
                            {
                                    sleep(2000);
                                    System.out.println("Score has changed");
                                    if (r.nextInt() % 2 == 0)
                                            m_nPointsA++;
                                    else
                                            m_nPointsB++;
                                    m_renderer.render(m_sessionId);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

and the web page pushexample.xhtml that displays the current score:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:icecore="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/core"
  xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
</h:head>                                   

<h:body>
<ice:outputText value="Current score: #{scoreManager.currentScore}"/>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not exactly what we were trying to do, but it does the trick, thanks.